# Transcribe adding 'favicon.ico' to url on language switch

Tags: ee2, structure, transcribe

I have EE 2.9.3, Transcribe 1.6.1 and Structure 3.3.14.7 running on a bilingual website and sometimes when the language switch button is pressed 'favicon.ico' is added the end of the url, thus giving a 404 error.

This addition of 'favicon.ico' seems to be random, it happens sometimes and is fine at other times.

I have absolutely no idea why this might be happening and have been advised to use the {exp:transcribe:no_match} tag, but I am completely lost and do not know where and how to use this tag in my template.

To display the language switcher I am using the following code:

```
{exp:transcribe:language_links}
     <ul class="languageSelector">
          {languages}
               <li {if current} class="activeList"{/if}><a href="{link}"{if current} class="active"{/if}>{name}</a></li>
          {/languages}
     </ul>
{/exp:transcribe:language_links}
```

Any help would be muchly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

After some advice from Tom at Transcribe I managed to fix this issue.

I got around this by adding {exp:transcribe:no_match segment="favicon.ico"} to the head section of my template so it is available on all pages.

This seems to have stopped 'favicon.ico' being added to the url.

Answer (score 0):

May be a long shot, but do you have a `.htaccess` file for your site? Does it contain ReWrites (for freindly URL's ect)??

It could be an errand rewrite rule, designed to pass-through the favicon path but in fact transforming your URL incorrectly...

Also, please supply example links from the switcher (i.e. the output of `{link}` so we can inspect this...

Comment: Hey Blatant, thanks for coming back to me. I actually got some help from Tom at Transcribe and he advised me to add `{exp:transcribe:no_match segment="favicon.ico"}` to the head section of my template so it is available on all pages. This seems to have stopped it, but I am still not sure why it was happening in the first place. I do have an .htaccess file but it is just the standard EE example from their site to remove index.php from the urls. A strange one but all seems to be good now. Thanks again.

Comment: Thats cool, please post the answer so you can confirm what you said as the answer, it'll help others if they have the issue. Seems that Tom at Transcribe know what this issue is so he'd be the guy to ask whty it happens!